# How to modify value as parameters in lambdas?

Tags: c++, callback

In my program, I have a global static value like this:
`static bool done=false`

which is taken by callback like this:

```
Library::CallbackType callback(bool& isDone, par1type& par1,....){
    return [&isDone,&par1,...](par0type par0){
        if(conditionTrue){
            doSomething();
        } else {
            thread([isDone,par1]()mutable{
                cleanUp();
                isDone=true;
            }).detach():
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem is when I call the code:

```
library->doCallback(callback(done,p1,...));
```

its code is generally working except the value of `done` is not changing as I intend.
So, what I got wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        thread([isDone,par1]()mutable{
```

This thread is capturing `isDone` by value. Which means that when it sets `isDone` to `true` it will set only its own copy of the original `isDone` to `true`.

This thread needs to capture it by reference, too. And, if that's the only reason for this to be a mutable lambda, the `mutable` can go away as well.

Answer (score 3):

When you create your thread, you are capturing `isDone` by value - i.e. the code within the lambda is working on a copy.  The `mutable` keyword doesn't change this, it just lets you change the copy.

The solution is to capture by reference (and then you can drop the `mutable`):

```
thread([&isDone,par1](){...
```